# Table Schema problem, column with multiple dependencies

Tags: schema, table

I have a product table shown below:

```
 CREATE TABLE(
        Id_Product INT PRIMARY KEY,
        Product_SKU INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        Product_Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
        Product_Section nvarchar(100) NULL,
        Product_Group nvarchar(100) NULL,
        Product_SubGroup nvarchar(100) NULL
    )
```

In my opinion this table has a problem with Product *Section*, *Group* and *Subgroup* but I want to verify it if I am correct.

The columns are correlated. *Subgroup* for example, has a dependency with *id_product* but also with *Group* and *Section*, this can cause problems when updating, inserting and deleting.

Is it right to normalize these columns, creating a table with only section, group and subgroup ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no problems in this table from database point of view.

The section/group/subgroup relation will have meaning on the client side, when you start showing the products with the tree-like navigation. But that is a completely correct way to define multi-level grouping.